# How to match partial values in different columns excel

Tags: excel, return, find, match

Hope you are doing well.

I am new in this team and in this tech world and I would appreciate some of your time and experience.

I want to check if a partial number in a cell exists in another cell of another column, and return the whole value.

Specifically, in the image.

Some cells in Column **F** contain a partial number of column **C**.

is there any formula to help me with that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBHVb.png)

I tried to use `FIND` and `VLOOKUP`, but since I am inexperienced I had not a success

Here is the sample data:

| Number | Partial Number (last 5 digits) |
| --- | --- |
| 900226001157835 | 90305 |
| 900108001389872 | 57479 |
| 900108001389588 | 17288 |
| 900108001389529 | 57577 |
| 900108001389856 | 57850 |
| 900108001389602 | 89840 |
| 900108001389792 | 90217 |
| 900108001389680 | 89137 |
| 900226001756925 | 90307 |
| 900108001480303 | 89911 |
| 900226001157404 |  |
| 900226001157479 |  |
| 900108001617288 |  |
| 900108001390456 |  |
| 900108001389228 |  |
| 900108001481627 |  |
| 900108001389282 |  |
| 900108001390113 |  |
| 900108001390012 |  |
| 900108001389267 |  |
| 900108001389092 |  |
| 900108001389840 |  |
| 900108001389937 |  |
| 900108001389479 |  |
| 900108001617212 |  |
| 900108001617292 |  |
| 900226001157850 |  |

Comment: Can you please show us what you tried?

Comment: I don't see any match from your input data, Are you looking for partial number from left to right, i.e. assuming the colum F, has the first numbers of column C or do you mean any partial number inside the large number in any position? Do you have your data stored as number or as text?

Comment: I provide a possible answer, please check it and please next time provide the sample data in table markdown format, it helps us to reproduce it in excel by copy and paste it. You can use this [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time and your comments.

Comment: @Vasko I updated your question so you can see how to enter the sample data in table markdown format using the tool I mentioned in my previous comment, so next time you know how to do it. In most cases, there is no need to use a screenshot, and it is not a good practice in Stackoverflow unless it is really necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming *no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question*. You can put the following formula in cell `D1` to look for a number match, considering the last `5` digits:

```
=LET(A, A1:A27, B, B1:B10,BYROW(B, LAMBDA(bb, TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(A,
 ISNUMBER(XMATCH(1*RIGHT(A,5), bb)), "Not Found")))))
```

If you don't expect to find more than one result per partial number, then you can remove the `TEXTJOIN` call.

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

The input data is stored as a number in Excel, that is why after `RIGHT` call I need to convert it back to a number, multiplying it by `1`. If the input data are numbers stored as text, it is not really necessary.

Comment: Actually, those 5 digits are the last part of some cells in column C